# How to use preg_replace to remove part of url address?

Tags: php, html, regex, preg-replace

I have some HTML code like this:

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/documentos/Servicios/SUCRE/sucDoc19.pdf&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=sf0JUrmjIc3Nswb154CgDQ&amp;ved=0CCkQFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNGfXg_9x83U3pYr6JfkJcWuXv8X0Q">
```

I need to clean my code to get something like this

```
<a href="http://mysite.com/documentos/Servicios/SUCRE/sucDoc19.pdf">
```

using `preg_replace`.

My code is the following:

```
$serp = preg_replace('&amp;sa=(.*)" ', '" ', $serp);
```

and it doesn't work.

BTW i need to restrict search with preg_replace until the FIRST entrance, i.e. i need to replace all html from `&amp;sa=` to the FIRST `"`, but now it search from `&amp;sa=` to the LAST `"`...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the delimiter.
So your code looks like:

```
$serp = preg_replace('/&amp;sa=(.*)" /', '" ', $serp);
```

okay, if you want to delete everything till the **first** quote then you can try the following instead of regex:

```
$temp = substr($serp,strpos($serp,'&amp;sa='),strpos($serp,'"',strpos($serp,'&amp;sa=')));
$serp = str_replace($temp,"",$serp);
```

Comment: Please don't post your own just to say "someone else said this" and harass the asker into accepting your answer. It's not fair to the other user. Just upvote the other answer instead.

Comment: @BoltClock sorry, but then my answer has something more too, i also helped the question-asker  in deleting everything till the first quote. but still i apologize, i'll have to get used to stackoverflow i am a newbie you see. This is just my third day at stackoverflow..

Comment: Your *original* answer did not have something more. Your original answer simply acknowledged that someone else had posted this long before you did, and only that. You then posted a comment asking the OP to accept your answer. That's not OK. Please don't do this again.

Answer (score 2):

You're missing the regex delimiters.

```
$serp = preg_replace('/&amp;sa=(.*)" /', '" ', $serp);
```

will give you [this](http://codepad.org/tcc9uUY3).

Comment: much tnks for Your answer! it's useful for me

Answer (score 0):

Just another regex to do it :)

```
$text = '<a href="http://mysite.com/documentos/Servicios/SUCRE/sucDoc19.pdf&amp;sa=U&amp;ei=sf0JUrmjIc3Nswb154CgDQ&amp;ved=0CCkQFjAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNGfXg_9x83U3pYr6JfkJcWuXv8X0Q" target="_blank">';

$text = preg_replace('/(&amp;sa=[^"]*)/', '', $text);

echo $text;

// Output:
<a href="http://mysite.com/documentos/Servicios/SUCRE/sucDoc19.pdf" target="_blank">
```

You can try it [HERE](http://codepad.org/vxpJIquU) (thks to hjpotter92 for this tool)